# Data versioning of "Hello_World" tutorial

Tags: kedro

i have added "versioned: true" in the "catalog.yml" file of the "hello_world" tutorial.

```
example_iris_data:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/01_raw/iris.csv
  versioned: true
```

Then when I used 
"kedro run" to run the tutorial, it has error as below:
"VersionNotFoundError: Did not find any versions for CSVDataSet".

May i know what is the right way for me to do versioning for the "iris.csv" file? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try versioning one of the downstream outputs. For example, add this entry in your `catalog.yml`, and run `kedro run`

```
example_train_x:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/02_intermediate/example_iris_data.csv
  versioned: true
```

And you will see `example_iris.data.csv` directory (not a file) under `data/02_intermediate`. The reason `example_iris_data` gives you an error is that it's the starting data and there's already `iris.csv` in `data/01_raw` so, Kedro cannot create `data/01_raw/iris.csv/` directory because of the name conflict with the existing `iris.csv` file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thx for your answer! May i know how to use Kedro to do data versioning for raw data? I read the documentation, it seems will add a time stamp in the folder directory, does it means for every run in different time, the raw data will save another copy in hard disk? if like this, will data versioning of Kedro take a lot of hard disk space?

Comment: The raw data is coming from outside of Kedro (not going through transformation in Kedro pipeline), and there's a single source of truth in data (see the FAQ in https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/06_resources/01_faq.html#what-is-data-engineering-convention), so that's why Kedro doesn't support data versioning (because there would be multiple source of truth if done). It will create another copy in hard disk (or cloud storage). The data versionin is similar to S3 versioning to that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that when Kedro tries to load the dataset, it looks for a file in `data/01_raw/iris.csv/<load_version>/iris.csv` and, of course, cannot find such path. So if you really want to enable versioning for your input data, you can move `iris.csv` like:

```sh
mv data/01_raw/iris.csv data/01_raw/iris.csv_tmp
mkdir data/01_raw/iris.csv
mv data/01_raw/iris.csv_tmp data/01_raw/iris.csv/<put_some_timestamp_here>/iris.csv
```

You wouldn't need to do that for any intermediate data as this path manipulations are done by Kedro automatically when it saves a dataset (but not on load).